# EventBridge rule not triggering Lambda yml

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I wrote a permission to allow it to trigger my Lambda function and an eventbridge yml to trigger the function. However, when yml is run with cloud formation, a stack is created but no triggering occurs.

```
Resources:
 LambdaFunction:
 Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
 Properties:
  Code:
    S3Bucket: bucketname
    S3Key: lambda_function.py.zip
  Runtime: python3.9
  FunctionName: WebScrabber
  Role: role.arn
  Layers:
    - layer.arn
  Timeout: 100
  Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
```

---

```
 Resources:
  ScheduledRule:
   Type: AWS::Events::Rule
   Properties:
    ScheduleExpression: cron(55 * * * ? *)
    State: ENABLED
    Targets:
     - Arn: function.arn
       Id: TargetFunctionV1
```

---

```
Resources:
 EventsPermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
   FunctionName: function.arn
   Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
   Principal: events.amazonaws.com
   SourceArn: event.arn
```

what should I do?

Normally, the function should be triggered every hour at 33 minutes.

Comment: Please correct the formatting of your post.

Comment: Also, your Lambda function appears to be named `LambdaFunction`, not `function`.

Comment: @jarmod I edited my code

Comment: What does `function.arn` resolve to? Is this something you copied from a website? Your function is not called `function` so it's not clear what `function.arn` represents.

Comment: Your template looks good, that is if variable like `function.arn` is just a representation of the actual `CfnRef`. Did you check if there's a CW Log created by your Lambda? Maybe it's being triggered but the function is throwing an error?